# Attempting to subtract a percentage on list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I'm trying to subtract 30% (of tax) from each indexed i number in my list of profit, however when running my code get I get thrown the type error:

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

I've attempted to pull out each individual element into floating variables but have had no luck, any help would be appreciated.

I've attempted to pull out each individual element into floating variables but have had no luck, any help would be appreciated.

I originally was multiplying by 0.70 inside the code but moved to a variable for clarity.

```
for i in range(len(revenue)):
    profit[i] = [
        revenue[i] - expenses[i]
    ]
print("The profit for each month is:")
print(profit)
The profit for each month is:
[[2522.67], [1911.3900000000003], [-3707.790000000001], [-2914.3099999999995], [-599.9200000000001], [7265.24], [8210.550000000001], [3944.9700000000003], [3328.3899999999994], [-2238.6500000000015], [659.5999999999985], [11629.54]]

percentage = 0.7
for i in range(len(profit)):
    tax[i] = [
        profit[i] * percentage
    ]
print("The profit after tax for each month is:")
print(tax)
```

I would expect to get a new list with a value being 30% of each within my profit list, instead I get thrown this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-644d71aa4363> in <module>
      2 for i in range(len(profit)):
      3     tax[i] = [
----> 4         profit[i] * percentage
      5     ]
      6 print("The profit after tax for each month is:")

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: The way you've written this, each item in profit is a list: `[1911.3900000000003]`. It doesn't seem like this is necessary. You could just set profit[i] = revenue[i] - expenses[i]` with out the enclosing `[ ]`. Then each item is simply a number and you can multiply it without error.

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks Mark, that fixed the problem. Could you please explain how removing the brackets fixed the issue?

- Apologies, just re-read, cheers!

Comment: This code  `profit[i] = [ revenue[i] - expenses[i] ]` makes each item in `profit` a list because brackets create lists — profit is then a list of lists. It doesn't make sense to multiple a list by a float. Removing the `[ ]` makes `profit` a list of numbers, which I think is what you want.